# Lista encadeada sem cabeça, problema na função interseccão

Tags: c, lista, runtime

Estou fazendo um série de função com lista encadeada sem cabeça, porém uma função chamada Interseccão não está funcionando corretamente, o problema compila sem erros porém essa função especificamente não roda e o programa apresenta runtime erro, nessa função deve passar como parametro duas lista e a função me retorna uma terceira lista com a interseccao das duas listas. Segue o código abaixo:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct reg {
     int conteudo;
     struct reg *prox;
};

typedef struct reg celula;

void insere (celula **p, int x) {
     celula *novo, *q;
     q = *p;
     novo = (celula *)malloc(sizeof(celula));
     novo->conteudo = x;

     if (*p == NULL) {
          novo->prox = NULL;
          *p = novo;
     }

     else {
           while (q->prox != NULL)
                  q = q->prox;

           novo->prox = q->prox;
           q->prox = novo;
     }
}

void imprima (celula *p) {
     celula *q;
     if (p == NULL) printf ("Nao");
     else {
          for (q = p; q != NULL; q = q->prox)
                printf ("%d ", q->conteudo);
         printf ("\n");
      }
}

int NumElementos (celula *p) {
     celula *q;
     int n = 0;

     for (q = p; q != NULL; q = q->prox)
         n++;

return n;
}

int Pertence (celula *p, int x) {
     celula *q; int pt;
     q = p;

     while (q != NULL && q->conteudo != x)
           q = q->prox;

     if (q->conteudo == x) pt = 1;
     else pt = 0;

return pt;
}

celula *Interseccao (celula *p, celula *q) {
     celula *aq, *ap, *r = NULL;
     int aux;

     for (ap = p; ap !=NULL; ap = ap->prox) {
           for (aq = q; aq != NULL; aq = aq->prox) {
                aux = aq->conteudo;
                   if (Pertence(ap, aux) ==  1) {
                          if (Pertence(r, aux) == 0)
                                insere(&r, aux);
                 }
           }
      }
    return r;
}

int main () {
     celula *lista = NULL;
     celula *lst = NULL;
     celula *lis = NULL;

     int ne, p;

     insere (&lista, 8);
     insere (&lista, 2);
     insere (&lista, 1);
     insere (&lista, 3);
     insere (&lista, 9);
     imprima(lista);
     ne = NumElementos (lista);
     printf ("%d ", ne);
     p = Pertence(lista, 3);
     if (p == 0) printf("\n pertence");
     else printf("\npertence\n");
     insere (&lst, 7);
     insere (&lst, 3);
     insere (&lst, 5);
     insere (&lst, 1);
     imprima(lst);
     lis = Interseccao(lista, lst);
     imprima(lis);

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função `Pertence()` não está verificando se o parâmetro `p` (atribuído à variável local `q`) é um ponteiro nulo e, ao acessar o elemento `conteudo`, ocorre o erro no *runtime*.

Basta alterar o `if` dentro da função para fazer essa verificação antes do acesso:

```
int Pertence (celula *p, int x) {
     celula *q; int pt;
     q = p;

     while (q != NULL && q->conteudo != x)
           q = q->prox;

     // AQUI  => verifica se q é diferente de NULL antes de acessar conteudo 
     if (q != NULL && q->conteudo == x) pt = 1;
     else pt = 0;

return pt;
}
```

O resultado da execução, após a alteração:

```
8 2 1 3 9
5
pertence
7 3 5 1
3 1       <== interseccão
```